# extracting file inside of directory with miniz

Tags: c++, zip

Is there someone that can explain me how i can get files from directories inside a zipfile.
I use c++ and miniz(code.google.com/p/miniz/). thank you in advance.
here my code i have that i use right now:

```
size_t uncomp_size;
mz_bool status;
mz_zip_archive zip_archive;

memset(&zip_archive, 0, sizeof(zip_archive));
status = mz_zip_reader_init_file(&zip_archive, "data.zip", 0);
if (!status){
    puts("failed to open zip file\n");
    return 0;
}
try{
    void* p = NULL;
    std::string file_to_extract = "data//test.txt";
    int file_index = mz_zip_reader_locate_file(&zip_archive, file_to_extract.c_str(), NULL, MZ_ZIP_FLAG_IGNORE_PATH);
    if (file_index < 0)
    {
        mz_bool is_dir = mz_zip_reader_is_file_a_directory(&zip_archive,file_index);
        if(is_dir){
            throw std::exception("file_index = folder");
        }else{
            throw std::exception("cannot find file in zip(0)");
        }
    }

    p = mz_zip_reader_extract_to_heap(&zip_archive, file_index, &uncomp_size, NULL);
    if(!p){
        throw std::exception("cannot find file in zip(1)");
    }
    std::fstream fp1("test.txt",ios::binary|ios::out);
    fp1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p),uncomp_size);
    fp1.close();
    delete p;
}catch(std::exception ex){
    cout << ex.what() << endl; 
}
mz_zip_reader_end(&zip_archive);
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is working for me using miniz from [here](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/).

```
string str_zip;    // The zip archive in string form.
string str_unzip;  // The uncompressed contents of the first file in the zip archive.

// Read in or assign zip contents to the string.
// In my case I receive the zip file via a web service.  
// The processing all takes place in memory.  
// But you can easily read a file's contents into the zipfile string, as well.

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned int uint;

mz_zip_archive zip_archive;
mz_bool status;

// Now try to open the archive.
memset(&zip_archive, 0, sizeof(zip_archive));

// You can provide the zip data in memory as I did...
status = mz_zip_reader_init_mem(&zip_archive, str_zip.c_str(), str_zip.size(), 0);

// Or you can just give a filename...
// status = mz_zip_reader_init_file(&zip_archive, "myfile.zip", 0);

if (!status)
{
    cout << "zip file appears invalid..." << endl;
    return;
}

// Get the first file in the archive.
if (mz_zip_reader_get_num_files(&zip_archive) != 1)
{
    cout << "zip file does not contain our 1 file..." << endl;
    return;
}

mz_zip_archive_file_stat file_stat;
if (!mz_zip_reader_file_stat(&zip_archive, 0, &file_stat))
{
    cout << "zip file read error..." << endl;
    mz_zip_reader_end(&zip_archive);
    return;
}

// Unzip the file to heap.
size_t uncompressed_size = file_stat.m_uncomp_size;
void* p = mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap(&zip_archive, file_stat.m_filename, &uncompressed_size, 0);
if (!p)
{
    cout << "mz_zip_reader_extract_file_to_heap() failed..." << endl;
    mz_zip_reader_end(&zip_archive);
    return;
}

str_unzip.assign((const char*)p,uncompressed_size);

// Close the archive, freeing any resources it was using
mz_free(p);
mz_zip_reader_end(&zip_archive);
```

Comment: Since this got downvoted, I'm wondering if it didn't work for someone.  Works for me, but it's probably now out of sync with the latest miniz code.  Let me know if there is more specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for this.

Lets we have;

In your C directory:

```
+-- ZipFile /
    +-- folder1 /
    +-- file1         
    +-- folder2 /
        +--file2.1
        +--file2.2
        +--file2.3
```

```c
bool decompress_folders_inside_zip()
{
    const std::string archive_name = "ZipFile.zip";
    const std::string decompress_path = "C:\\";

    mz_zip_archive archive {};

    boost::filesystem::path dec_path { decompress_path + archive_name };

    if (!mz_zip_reader_init_file(&archive, dec_path.string().c_str(), 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    const int file_cnt = (int)mz_zip_reader_get_num_files(&archive);

    if (0 == file_cnt)
    {
        return false;
    }

    mz_zip_archive_file_stat file_stat;

    if (!mz_zip_reader_file_stat(&archive, 0, &file_stat))
    {
        mz_zip_reader_end(&archive);
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < file_cnt; ++i)
    {
        mz_zip_reader_file_stat(&archive, i, &file_stat);

        if (mz_zip_reader_is_file_a_directory(&archive, i))
        {
            boost::filesystem::path dir(decompress_path + file_stat.m_filename);
            boost::filesystem::create_directories(dir.parent_path());
            continue;
        }

        boost::filesystem::path file_out(decompress_path + file_stat.m_filename);

        boost::filesystem::path out_file(file_out.parent_path().generic_string() + "/" + file_out.filename().string());

        if (!mz_zip_reader_extract_to_file(&archive, i, out_file.string().c_str(), 0))
        {
            mz_zip_reader_end(&archive);
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!mz_zip_reader_end(&archive))
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "Completed" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```